# Find objects in an array of objects based on the values in an array of values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Say I have the array

```
const idArray = ["935", "933", "930"];
```

And I would like to get the objects that have an id property that matches one of the values in the `idArray`

```
const objectsArray= [
  { 
    name: "Kevin", 
    color: "red", 
    id: "935"
  },
  { 
    name: "Ana", 
    color: "white", 
    id: "815"
  },
  { 
    name: "Maria", 
    color: "silver", 
    id: "035"
  },
  { 
    name: "Victor", 
    color: "red", 
    id: "935"
  },
  { 
    name: "Vanessa", 
    color: "red", 
    id: "933"
  },
]
```

So in this case, i would like to return the objects that have the names:  `Kevin`, `Vanessa` and `Victor`.

Comment: So, where are you stuck? :-) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Your data structure not allow to solve the problem efficiently, i would suggest you to change (if possible) the array of objects to and object that the key will be the id, and the value will be an object with name & color

Comment: @felixmosh Turning it into hash table would make for faster queries for sure, but I honestly doubt that this information is somewhat useful to OP if he/she struggles with the posted problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can filter based on the `idArray`. This could potentially be slow if both arrays are large since it needs to look through `idArray` each time:

```js
const objectsArray= [{   name: "Kevin",   color: "red",   id: "935"},{   name: "Ana",   color: "white",   id: "815"},{   name: "Maria",   color: "silver",   id: "035"},{   name: "Victor",   color: "red",   id: "935"},{   name: "Vanessa",   color: "red",   id: "933"},]

const idArray = ["935", "933", "930"];

let res =  objectsArray.filter(o => idArray.includes(o.id))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: @MatusDubrava you could vote to close the question if you like.

Comment: @MatusDubrava the reason Google is helpful is because of answers to questions like this

Answer (score 0):

yes actually it is very easy to achieve using filter.

```js
const idArray = ["935", "933", "930"];
const objectsArray = [
  {
    name: "Kevin",
    color: "red",
    id: "935"
  },
  {
    name: "Ana",
    color: "white",
    id: "815"
  },
  {
    name: "Maria",
    color: "silver",
    id: "035"
  },
  {
    name: "Victor",
    color: "red",
    id: "935"
  },
  {
    name: "Vanessa",
    color: "red",
    id: "933"
  },
];


function getObjectsInArray(objectsArray, idsArray){
  return objectsArray.filter(o=>{
    return idsArray.indexOf(o.id) !== -1;
  })
}

console.log(getObjectsInArray(objectsArray, idArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const objectsArray= [{   name: "Kevin",   color: "red",   id: "935"},{   name: "Ana",   color: "white",   id: "815"},{   name: "Maria",   color: "silver",   id: "035"},{   name: "Victor",   color: "red",   id: "935"},{   name: "Vanessa",   color: "red",   id: "933"},]
    
    console.log(find(objectsArray));
    
    function find(objArray){
        const idArray = ["935", "933", "930"];
        var results = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++){
          if(idArray.includes(objArray[i].id)){
            results.push(objArray[i]);
          }
        }
        return results;
       }
```